# how Interllj jrebel setting?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, jrebel

Tomcat runs and the service goes up well.
but jrebel not working ,
I also confirmed that the J-level has not expired.
Due to the nature of my work, I clone and use projects from several clients.

If you look at rebel.xml in the existing jar file, it appears as a 'D:/git/GW7-develop/company-framework/company-framework-parent/target/classes' path.

But I want to modify it to suit my route. 'D:/dev/wsp/myproject/target/ekp/WEB-INF/lib/company-framework-parent-4.4.0.jar!/rebel.xml'

How can I change the settings to the path I set rather than the path in the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the path in the rebel.xml file, then replace the rebel.xml in the JAR file with the modified file (generally this is achieved by rebuilding the JAR from source, assuming you've kept the rebel.xml in your resources directory).

Instructions for project configuration here: https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/ide/intellij.html#project-configuration